# Find number of times marks came less than previous in a group

Tags: r, data.table

For the dataset

```
data <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4),
                   Class =c("Geo", "Geo","M","M", "B", "C", "D","D", "L", "P", "Y", "Z"),
                   Marks = c(100,150,100,150,100,150,100,100,100, 90, 80, 100))
```

```
    ID  Class Marks
 1:  1   Geo  100
 2:  1   Geo  150
 3:  1   M    100
 4:  1   M    150
 5:  1   B    100
 6:  2   C    150
 7:  2   D    100
 8:  2   D    100
 9:  3   L    100
10:  3   P     90
11:  3   Y     80
12:  4   Z    100
```

If we have to find the number of times the mark became less for each group by "ID" . For example: For **ID 1** it will start with first row and assign zero, then go to next row and compare if mark less than previous row mark. If yes then keep a counter as 1 .Increase this counter for every decrease in next comparisons.

The final output should be a sum of all decreases counter in a new variable.Note: The first row for each variable will not be compared as it doesn't have a previous mark. It should always start with second row in a group.
Also there should be a mark column which shows only the first mark of each ID.

Desired output:

```
Final_data <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
                         Marks_first = c(100, 150, 100, 100),
                         Times_detoriated = c(2,1,2,1))
```

```
   ID  Marks_first   Times_detoriated
1:  1  100              2  
2:  2  150              1  
3:  3  100              2  
4:  4  100              1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `data.table` methods for the data.table object.  Here, we group by 'ID', `if` the number of rows (`.N`) is 1, then return 1 `else`, return the count of adjacent element difference that are negative

```
library(data.table)
data[, .(Marks = if(.N == 1) 1L else
       sum((Marks - shift(Marks)) < 0, na.rm = TRUE)), by = ID]
#    ID Marks
#1:  1     2
#2:  2     1
#3:  3     2
#4:  4     1
```

---

If we need the `first` 'Marks', just use `first` of 'Marks' as a new summary column as well

```
data[, .(Marks_first = first(Marks), Time_detoriated = if(.N == 1) 1L else
    sum((Marks - shift(Marks)) < 0, na.rm = TRUE)), ID]
#    ID Marks_first Time_detoriated
#1:  1         100               2
#2:  2         150               1
#3:  3         100               2
#4:  4         100               1
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, one more query, if I also want to have a column which has the first Mark value. What should I add to the code? I will edit the question to show this as well

Answer (score 1):

Hope the code below with `aggregate` + `diff` could help

```
aggregate(.~ID, data,function(x) ifelse(length(x)==1,1,sum(diff(x)<0)))
```

which gives

```
  ID Marks
1  1     2
2  2     1
3  3     2
4  4     1
```

Comment: What is there are multiple columns and we need to do it on any selected column?

Comment: @Deb Then you should specify `Mark ~ ID`